# Zoom & Pan draws wrong lines in Jquery Flot Chart

Tags: canvas, flot

I am developing a chart with Jquery Flot Chart.
The problem is weird. When I zoom and pane, the behaviour of chart changes.

Look at the this samples.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provice your code, data, options and used plugins (maybe as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more infos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
I tried to implement it with the jsfiddle and I found the Spline plugin is the problem. I removed it from series and it solved.